# Reboot and Select Proper Device, won't boot and doesn't seem to detect hard drive

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, bootloader, boot-repair

I'm using Lubuntu 16.04 on my PC and then suddenly it hangs. After pressing the power button off, all of sudden it won't boot into Lubuntu and has **Reboot and Select Proper Device** during boot.

All i know is before it happened I executed:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and it asks me to upgrade **grub2**, so i  updated it. Then after a few minutes, the computer started getting slow and it hanged.

I've already tried **boot-repair** but it doesn't have the **Recommended Repair** option. It's missing.

So i just pressed the **Create bootinfo summary** on boot-repair and this is the result: http://paste2.org/BEpLz7W4

I've executed

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and this is the result, it seems it doesn't detect my partition at all.

```
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 820.3 MiB, 860176384 bytes, 1680032 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 1.9 GiB, 1999568384 bytes, 3905407 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x710e579d

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       63 3904991 3904929  1.9G  6 FAT16




Disk /dev/zram0: 363.5 MiB, 381194240 bytes, 93065 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/zram1: 363.5 MiB, 381194240 bytes, 93065 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

When trying to reinstall using Live CD, it doesn't detect my hard disk
[image]

After executing **gnome-disk-utility**, this is the result

[image]

**Note**:

- I only have Lubuntu 16.04 installed on my PC not dual boot.
- All the commands above are run on Lubuntu Live CD session.

Comment: It sounds like your hard drive suffered a mechanical failure. When you boot your computer into the BIOS or UEFI, does the hard drive show up there?

Comment: @blendenzo, w8, It seems like that's the case, How would i deal with it? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably either an electrical failure (the hard drive controller board failed) or a mechanical failure (the hard drive motor failed).

A mechanical failure is often accompanied by strange noises coming from the disk. If it is an electrical failure, you will not even hear the disk spinning up when you start the computer. (Of course, this only applies to spinning disk drives, not SSDs.) The good news is that your situation sounds like it might actually be an electrical failure.

If it is an electrical failure, you may be able to replace the controller board yourself and recover your data. You can order new controller boards online, or obtain a working identical drive and use its controller board to repair your broken drive. Here is an Instructable explaining how one person was able to obtain the correct parts and make a repair like this: http://www.instructables.com/id/Successful-Hard-Drive-Controller-Replacement/

In the case of a mechanical failure, you will not be able to do the recovery yourself. If you absolutely need the data recovered, you can send it out to a professional data recovery service, but that could cost upwards of 1000 USD, and there is no guarantee that the drive platters did not suffer damage in the mechanical failure. (If you can't send it out right now, but you might be able to in the future, store the drive in an anti-static bag until you are able.)

Comment: i think the last command i've executed is **sudo apt-get upgrade** w/c instructs me to update **grub2**. 

And rebooting, and pressing F12, it seems like my hard disk is detected, but it just boots to black screen w/ blinking cursor

Comment: Well then you don't have a total drive failure. Your comment above made me think you had already checked and the drive wasn't showing up. If you can see the device in boot options list, but you can't see it in gnome-disk-utility or gparted when you boot to Lubuntu live disc, then it would be hard to know how to recover the data. You might try a program called SpinRite which can repair physical sector problems on the disk which might be preventing it from being listed https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm (SpinRite is not free)

Comment: my hard drive is not detected again on pressing F12, it was detected just a while ago

Comment: Could be a bad data connection (the data cable in a PC, drive or data ribbon could have jostled loose in a laptop), bad power connection, the sata controller on your motherboard could be faulty.  In order to find out if the problem is with the drive, try plugging it in to another computer using a different cable, or use a USB drive dock. If it is consistently being recognized using one of those methods, then the issue is likely with the cable or the board in your computer.  If the problem still occurs when the drive is plugged in somewhere else, you might try replacing the controller board.

Comment: thanks for being so responsive mate, but i'm still having a problem. After being stuck, i've shutdown my computer for a while. Then after a few hours, i've powered it on, and boot to live USB.

And then i run **gnome-disks** and suddenly it detects my harddisk but this time it incorrectly listed it as only 4GB when in fact it is 500GB